# Failure INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED <provider> has empty authorities when running cordova app on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I've got a small Ionic android which was running just fine. After upgrading to Android 7.1 SDK, I get the following error when running `cordova run --target=emulator-5554 android --verbose`:

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl444999769.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #103): <provider> has empty authorities attribute]
```

This is line 103 of `platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.marianhello.bgloc.sync.DummyContentProvider"
    android:authorities="@string/content_authority"
    android:exported="false"
    android:syncable="true" />
```

It appears to me like the authorities attribute is defined, yet on some examples online I see that it has the app name in there while I have `@string/content_authority` instead. Unfortunately editing `AndroidManifest.xml` is worthless as it is generated.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "travellogapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.15.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "^7.1.1",
    "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release": "^1.4.4",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.4.6",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": {
        "ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
        "SMALL_ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
        "ACCOUNT_NAME": "@string/app_name",
        "ACCOUNT_LABEL": "@string/app_name",
        "ACCOUNT_TYPE": ".account",
        "CONTENT_AUTHORITY": "",
        "GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11+",
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION": "23+"
      },
      "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
        "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "XXX",
        "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "XXX",
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.0.1",
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out as soon as I wrote my question.

The provider tag was introduced by `cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation`. The line `android:authorities="@string/content_authority"` says that the `authorities` value is defined in a `string` (variable) called `content_authority`. You will find the variable defined in your `config.xml` and 'packgage.json':

```
"cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": {
        ...
        "CONTENT_AUTHORITY": ""
      }
```

For some reason, it ended up being empty for me. Removing and adding the plugin fixed it by setting it to:

```
"cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": {
    ...
    "CONTENT_AUTHORITY": "$PACKAGE_NAME"
    }
```